# Create adjacency singly linked list

Tags: c

I have ADT for graph like:

```
typedef struct element {
  int info;
  struct element *link;
} Tnode;

typedef struct graphAdjList {
  int nodes;
  Tnode *adjList[MAX];  // array of 20 pointers to Tnode
} Tgraph;

Tgraph *readGraph(FILE *fd);
void printGraph(Tgraph *g);
void dfs(Tgraph *g, int start, int visited[], int pred[]);
void destroyGraph(Tgraph *g);
```

and enclosing file "maze.txt" with following content:

```
0 1 6 8
1 0 2 3
2 10 11
3 1 4 12
4 3 13
5 4 6 9
6 5 7
7 8 9
8 0 7 14
9 15 5 7
10 2
11 2
12 3
13 4
14 8
15 9
```

where 0 1 6 8 means node number 0 has (one directional) connections to nodes 1, 6 and 8. Now I don't really know how to construct graph based on above list through method readGraph(). Could you guys please point me out detailed implementation cause i'm newbie in C ? Thanks alot

Comment: Where did this ADT come from? It doesn't appear to be capable of multiple links from one node.

Comment: come from my teacher >.< I also suspect but he's sure it's right

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your teacher intends for you to read the graph into an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list).

Here is a [sample implementation](http://pastecode.com/cQ) in C99.

Save it to a file named `maze.c` and then compile it with (for example):

`gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Werror -std=c99 -o maze maze.c`

I didn't implement the `dfs()` function as it wasn't entirely clear to me what it's supposed to do. I'm assuming there is some text that goes along with your assignment explaining the requirements of each function. You will probably have to rewrite the `printGraph()` function to match the assignment requirements as well.

Comment: hi, so for each node you will allocate new memory for it even it already existed in previous line, right? For instance at first line, we have vertex number 6 which has link to vertex 8 and at line 7 we have vertex number 6 but now links to 5. This will lead vertex 6 directly point to 5 and skip 8 at first line!!

Comment: dfs(Tgraph *g, int start, int visited[], int pred[]) does the depth-first type search process, starting from the start node, marking non-zero to all nodes visited to the visited[] array, and marking to the pred[] array which edge was leading to this vertex (pred[5]=3 means that vertex 3 has an edge to the vertex 5)

Comment: Yes, a new node is allocated for each edge. An image search on Google will probably be helpful for understanding how the datatype is constructed.